# How can I find the highest value in a loop with pine script?

Tags: pine-script

I need to find the highest value within a loop. What I got is equal to "steps" using this formula

```
var float j =0
var int l = 0
for i = steps to maxma by steps
    
    if countreverses(i,Pivot) > j
        j := countreverses(i,Pivot)
        l := i
    else 
        l:= l
```

countreverses(i,Pivot) is a custom function! I want to get which "i" give me the highest output from the function.
I assumed if I put it in a loop whenever " countreverses(i,Pivot) " is higher than j I can extract i out of formula but the output is eqaul to "steps "

Answer (score 0):

The FOR LOOP in Pine returns the last statement in the FOR LOOP. So if you want to return your calculated variable, simply put it on the last line in the loop.

In your loop you calculate two variables, one is `j` and the other one is `l` although you don't do anything with that `l` so I assumed it is `j` that is important:

```
for i = steps to maxma by steps

    if countreverses(i,Pivot) > j
        j := countreverses(i,Pivot)
        l := i
    else 
        l:= l
    j
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
It gives me the same old result!

Comment: assuming steps = 10
for i = 10, countreverses(i,Pivot) is 3 and then for i = 30 (3rd step) countreverses(i,Pivot) is 5! Since 5>3, I expect that "i" would be equal to 30! but it's still the 10 (equals to 10)

Comment: `i` might be 30, which gets assigned to `l` however it is `j` that is returned from the loop. You don't do anything with `l`, it just get created, assigned a few values and then discarded (it does not retain its value when you exit the loop)